# copying array of string pointers to a new array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

we get input from user (command line) and store it in `in char* input[]`.
This input will look like this, when the user inputs all required information:

`input[]: add  John Smith (male) <relation> Emma Stone (female)`.

Then we want to copy it to `new_input[]` with 8 positions (for example `John` would be on the position 1). In our first example this will look like the same:

`new_input []: add  John Smith (male) <relation> Emma Stone (female)`

But there are possibilities that we don't get all the information from the user. Especially it is most likely we don't get the last name. So, during the copy we need to add some ‘if-statements’  to check if the user puts e.g. `Smith` or not. If not – we want write ‘NULL’ at the positions 2 and 6. The array looks then like:

`if input []: add John (male) <relation> Emma  (female)`

`new_input []: add  John NULL (male) <relation> Emma NULL (female)`

Unfortunately, we have difficulties with copying array of string pointers to a new array.

We tried `memcpy()`, `new_input[i] = input[i]` (in a for-loop).

EDIT:  here is code and  i also edit example above, (new_input with NULL on position 2 and 6 if last names are missing)

```
`int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
char* copy_input = NULL;
    int len_max = 256;
    int error = 1;
    char* input = (char*) malloc(len_max* sizeof(char)); 
if (argc == 1) 
    {
        while(1)
        {
            printf("cmd> "); 
            char read[len_max];
            input = fgets(read, len_max, stdin);
            int len = strlen(read);`

            if(read[len-1] == '\n')
            {
                read[len-1] = '\0';
            }
            copy_input = input;``

            error = handleUserInput (copy_input);
}`
```

in handle user command, we split string by space and check first string, if it is " add " , go to function addCommand (in)

`

```
int handleUserInput(char* input) // takes char input from main and compares type of command
{
    printf("input: %s\n",input );
    char* in[8];
    int i = 0;
    char* temp;
    char delimiter[] = " ";
    temp = strtok(input, delimiter);
    in[i++] = temp;
    while( temp != NULL)
    {
        temp = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
        in[i++] = temp;
        // printf("%s\n", temp);
    }
    if(!strcmp(in[0], "add"))
    {
        addCommand(in);
    }`
```

In function add command, we want to do copy input to new_input as i described above...

```
`int addCommand(char* input[]) //
{
char* new_input[];
```

`

Comment: `memcpy(new, old, count * sizeof old[0] );`

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the "difficulties" you're having? Perhaps try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? With examples of expected *and* actual output?

Comment: You should post the code that get the input to get an answer. I mean: is better to validate the input instead of post process user input.

Comment: please provide code to showcase what isnt working, you give a bunch of highlighted text which gives nothing we can help with without taking shots at the dark.

Comment: i posted a code that gets input, handles input in fucntion handleInputCommands ( here input is splitted and we check the first word), then input is sent to a function addCommand where we want to save it in new array so we would have fixed position of each string in array depending on user input... i hope this can help you to help me :)

Comment: @Totenkoph93 Please add example input and expected output of your code. Like sample input from the user, and what you want your final `char *inputs[]` array to look like.

Comment: @RoadRunner input from user is :  add FirstName Lastname [gender] relation FirstName LastName [gender]

Comment: @RoadRunner input from user is :  add FirstName Lastname [gender] relation FirstName LastName [gender]  .... but Lastname of both persons is optional... so i want to have this array of strings stored in fixed positions, NULL will be on place 2 and 6 if LastName is missing... My next step is then to check if FirstName in input[1] contains alphabetic signs, if gender is male or female, and so on.. im able to do those steps, my issue here is LastName which may not be in input, and i figured  that can be solved if each string is on fixed position and NULL for when a string ( lastname) is missing

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile.  Infact, it does not compile at all.  So what are you expecting us to do?   Perhaps read your mind as to the content of the missing code?

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) the returned type is `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting the returned value just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  3) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined as 1,  mulitplying anything by 1 has absolutely no effect.  Suggest removing that expression

Comment: regarding this line: `char read[len_max];`  `read()` is a well known system function so should not be used for a variable name.

Comment: you can save your self some stack space by making a `#define READ_MAX (256)` statement then using `READ_MAX everywhere the code is looking for that value.

Comment: the posted code for `main()` is missing a lot of statements.  The line: `if (argc == 1)` indicates that there could be optional command line parametersl but,  nowhere does the question indicate what (optional) command line parameters there could be.

Comment: @user3629249  there could be two command parameters, in this case second parameter is a .dot file, which i have to open and store in structure... but that was not the issue in this scope. for argc == 1 there are in total 5 commands and first one is "add person [gender] relation person [gender] " , for now im trying to solve this one  and later will focus on rest

Comment: @user3629249 i used some advices from you and other guys, my code now does compile properly, biggest problem was with allocating memory for input, which seems. i think i understand how to solve other issues im having, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the `new_input[i] = input[i]`
You're gonna assign the pointeur of `input[i]` to `the new_input[i]`
then thing is that it would not be a copy it's just a copy of the string personnal adress.
So if u want to make a real copy with it's "own memory" u need to first allocate a new string and then copy the content of the last string in the new.

(man strdup)

To copy an array of string pointer you will probably do a basic method wich mean to first allocate your double pointeur `(char **array)`
to receive your new content.
and then loop to copy all the content with the method that i've show you just before